# Touch events via HDMI

Tags: touch-event, lcd, hdmi

I need touch capable LCD panel that I need to connect to some sort of external computer. Panel itself does not contain any embedded computer, so no OS will run on it that could process touch events. Panel will be connected to external computer similar to Intel NUC via HDMI.

My question: Would I be able to handle touch events send from panel via HDMI without much trouble (special drivers, configuration etc.)?

External computer will have some flavor of Linux installed, which one is yet to be decided.

Touch events are similar to mouse events so I think X.org server would handle them transparently, or with some minor configuration.

I have seen it working with USB but not with HDMI.

There are USB ports on panel, but im not sure if it will transfer touch event through them when connected.

Note: I don't have panel yet, so can't just plug it in and try.

Panel will be something akin tho this (but not exactly) https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Wall-Mounted-LCD-Touch-Screen-Advertising_60650200010.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.235.50af4611aIelfv&s=p

Comment: I've never heard of a configuration like this. I don't think HDMI supports any signaling like you describe. HDMI can carry audio, and in some cases Ethernet, but to my knowledge, not USB or any other generic input-capable bus.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1155513/can-an-hdmi-cable-carry-a-mouse-a-keyboard-signal

Comment: Finally, this is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming, not computer hardware.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks for info, I have seen that HDMI might support ethernet, was hoping it might carry generic event too.